# Google Cloud Function triggered by play store private bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to setup a google Cloud Function that gets triggered whenever a user posts a review on Google Play. Because every review gets posted into a private storage bucket, I suppose it should work...

I am able to access the reviews locally (using gsutil or python API) but when I setup the cloud function for that bucket it gives the following error:

> Insufficient permissions to (re)configure a trigger (permission denied
>   for bucket ). Please, give owner permissions to the
>   editor role of the bucket and try again.

I'm using Google Cloud on my personal account, which has access to the Google Play Console of the referring app -- but its not the "main/original" account.

Given that I have access, what could be the problem here?

Comment: Cloud functions operate as a project editor of your gcp project, they don't use permissions tied to your personal account. Perhaps try going to that bucket and give owner access to all editors of the project, where you deploy the cloud functions. You might need to get the project-id to do that. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/bucket-level-iam

Comment: I'm not sure how I could do that , as I can't find that bucket in my account. Apparently the bucket for the PlayStore reviews is a "private" one. I have access to it because I have access to the PlayStore. Also, the "true" owner user, does not have google cloud setup, at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, this probably won't be possible right now. The bucket is owned by Google, so you can't make ACL modifications to it by hand, even if you were the owner of the Play project. Conversely, you can't authorize Functions to make API calls on behalf of any user/service account, so that won't work either. You could set-up a micro instance (free tier, yay), authorize with your account and set up a cron job as a workaround. But there goes 'serverless'...

Comment: eheh right! and there goes my idea ^^ thanks for explanation!